# Determing number of unique data files based on file name

Tags: matlab, file, dataset, load

I have a set of data, for example, with filenames as follow:

```
data1_1.mat
data1_2.mat
data1_3.mat
data2_1.mat
data2_2.mat
data3_1.mat
data4_1.mat
data4_2.mat
```

I want to be able to determine how many datasets there are (i.e. there are 4 here) and how many subsets of data each set has (i.e. 1 has 3, 2 has 2, 3 has 1, etc.) so I can perform work iteratively on these later. I would like to figure out the number of sets as perhaps a struct, and have each value of the struct correspond to the number of unique entries. I am not sure how to do this; is there a method related to `dir` that can be used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a single method to do all of the queried, and how you structure your data in memory is really up to you.  But since your files are already numbered, I would maintain a one-to-one mapping between the data's data structure and the numbering of the files (personal preference).

```
clc();
clear();

%   Grab information for all of the mat-files in the PWD
files = dir('*.mat');

%   Get only the filenames
fileNames = {files.name};

%   Grab the data set ID and convert the string to a double
allIDstr = regexp(fileNames(:),'data(\d)','tokens');
allIDs   = cellfun(@(c) str2double(c{1}),allIDstr);

%   Get the set of unique IDs and a vector that generates it given the original input
[setIDs,Iuni] = unique(allIDs);
disp(setIDs(:).');

%   Calculate the number of subsets for each unique ID using Iuni
nsubsets = diff(Iuni);
nsubsets = [nsubsets;numel(allIDs) - sum(nsubsets)];
disp(nsubsets(:).');

%   One way to organize data
data = cell(numel(setIDs),1);
for k = 1:numel(setIDs)
    data{k} = cell(nsubsets(k),1);
    for m = 1:nsubsets(k)
        data{k}{m} = load(fileNames{k},'-ascii');
    end
end

%   Get the data for the second set's second subset
workdata = data{2}{2};
```

This outputs:

```
     1     2     3     4
     3     2     1     2
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a combination of `dir`, `containers.Map` and string operations it is easily possible.

#### Sample code

```
dirPath = 'folder/*.mat';
files = dir(dirPath);

% Store all file information in a dictionary
dataSet = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');

for i = 1:length(files)
    parts = strsplit(erase(files(i).name, "data"), {'_', '.'});

    % Main set index
    fID = str2double(parts{1});

    % Add this file to set and increment counter of dictionary
    if dataSet.isKey(fID)
        setInfo = dataSet(fID);
        setInfo.count = setInfo.count + 1;
        setInfo.files{end+1} = files(i).name;
    else
        setInfo.count = 1;
        setInfo.files = {files(i).name};
    end
    dataSet(fID) = setInfo;
end

disp(dataSet)
```

Then, the sets can be found as `dataSet.keys()`, and the files in each set by accessing the key, such as:

```
>> dataSet(1)
ans = 

  struct with fields:

    count: 2
    files: {'data1_1.mat'  'data1_2.mat'}
```